# How to find which Firefox tab is playing audio without installing extensions?

Tags: firefox

On Chrome/Chromium/Brave there's a button that tells you which tabs are playing audio. On Firefox I can't find the same thing.

The best I can do is going to task manager and seeing which tab is using more CPU which normally is the one that is playing something.

Any solution for this?

Comment: I have _many_ open tabs in quite a few windows, and it's impossible to find a rogue tab, e.g. Youtube playing, without installing a Firefox addon. In my case [Tabhunter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabhunter/) helped me, really.

Comment: Not the perfect solution but in FF there is a "List all tabs" button that looks like '⌄', clicking it shows your open tabs as a vertical dropdown list and that looks much cleaner than just looking at the tabs row, because of the wider width, now it's much easier to notice the tab with the speaker icon on it, you can directly mute/unmute the tab by clicking the speaker icon or click the tab name and jump directly to it.

Answer (score 15):

I had this incredibly annoying problem for a long time & after reading your posts I wanted to solve this issue without a plugin.
I find the 'Audio Playing' icons to be essentially pointless, they are small and hard to see if you have many tabs open.

Solution:
I have discovered that it is possible to detect which tab is playing audio through the Firefox Task Manager which is in fact a resource manager/tracker.

Open the following url in your browser:
about:performance

On the right there should be three columns:
Type : Energy Impact : Memory
Select the energy column.

The tab playing the audio should be somewhere at the top of the list.
Double-click on the link for that tab and it will open in the browser and you can 'adjust' the audio.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this is literally the solution the OP mentioned in the question

Comment: Actually 'literally' they only mentioned the task manager, whereas I posted instructions on how to use it and discuss how it's more effective in practice than suggested solutions. If you read my post through you'll see I was responding to possible solutions that were posted, not literally to the original post, but on that point I added significant info not in the original post. I totally admit I didn't see the task manager line in the OP, it was late etc. but I'm not clear on what your point is here, are you raising an objection ? Perhaps you could walk me through it ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this should totally be the accepted solution! Thanks, it helped a lot, even with hundreds of tabs :)

Comment: did not work in my case (win11 + FF 121.0) as the task manager only has Memory and CPU usage columns)

Comment: @supernoob: Thank you! Very helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently another indicator was added in Firefox 91 that is visible even on tiny tabs:

[image: Little speaker badge shown on the tab icon]

The speaker badge on the tab icon appears when a tab is playing sounds. It can be clicked to (un)mute the tab.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain what's wrong with my answers and how they should be improved? I'd be happy to make them better, but you've left no constructive feedback.

Comment: I did not downvote, but the indicator is not helpful when a large number of tabs is opened. I was hoping for a short-cut for jumping to the currently playing tab.

Answer (score 0):

Since Firefox 89 it's spelled out explicitly below the tab title:

[image: Tab's title is shifted upwards and the word "Playing" is displayed below it.]

Versions 42 through 88 used a speaker icon next to the × button, just like Chrome-likes do.

Comment: It is showing playing even when the audio/video is paused.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio For me the indicator disappears about 3 seconds after pausing the video. Just tested on YouTube.

Comment: I have hundred of tabs. This is not a solution. :)

Comment: I also have multitudes of tabs open + even use the Izheil
 Multirow-Patcher for Quantum, And yes, the icon that shows a playing tab is small, and while you did not want an extension, I found one that does not say it accesses data:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/go-to-playing-tab-2/  Simply click on the button in the toolbar (if in the overflow, r. click on it  + choose Pin...) and choose Close playing tab . 

It also works with different windows. You can be in Window A and if something is playing in Window B, Window B will be focused in the playing tab. 5 stars:   898 Users

Answer (score -1):

No, unfortunately not. It shows Autoplay on every single tab and none of them indicate which one is active.

Tabs in Firefox - which one is playing?

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1235495)